# Pivoting dataframes in for loop Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, pivot

I'm trying to pivot dataframes inside a loop.

I heard that I can make changes on several dataframes if I have them inside a list, such as:

```
df_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4,...]
```

I have been using this method for a while to make changes on all dataframes, for example:

```
for df in df_list:
    df.drop('column_name',axis=1,inplace=True) #drops column from every dataframe in df_list
```

but there is something I am trying to do that doesn't produce any change in the dataframes.

Each dataframe looks something like:

```
Time        Value    hist
11:14:23    2.0      12
11:14:23    1.5      78
11:14:23    1.0      31
```

and I wanted it to look like:

```
Time      1.0      1.5      2.0
11:14:23  31       78       12
```

I tried this:

```
for df in df_list:
  df = df.pivot(index='Time',columns='Value', values='hist')
```

but after this loop, all dataframes remain unchanged.

What's even weirder is that if I do this individually for a dataframe, it works perfectly, it just doesn't work in the loop. The loop is necessary because there are over 20000 dataframes to make this change to.

All help is really valuable, thank you! :)

Comment: `df_list = [df.pivot(index='Time',columns='Value', values='hist') for df in df_list]`

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that `DataFrame.drop` or `DataFrame.pivot_table` creates a new DataFrame, you could go ahead with:

```
df_list = [df.pivot(index='Time',columns='Value', values='hist') for df in df_list]
```